# Known Plaintext Attack A5/2

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, known-plaintext-attack, linear-cryptanalysis

I am trying to understand the non-optimized known plaintext attack on A5/2 from [Barkan, Bikan and Keller](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/2006/CS/CS-2006-07.pdf).

I don't understand the construction of the equation system:
$$S_{R4_1} * S_1 = k$$

Where $S$ is the system's matrix and $k=k_1||k_2||k_3||k_4$.

How do I create the system's matrix $S_{R4_1}$ and $S_1$?

Comment: Formatting hint: you can use \$\$ prefix / appendix instead of a single \$ to create a centralized block formula.

Comment: It's my question too. Isn't there any to answer?